# how to access json Object from HTTP callback on Retrofit 2.0

Tags: android, json, android-studio, retrofit, retrofit2

hi i'm using retrofit to bring back a java object, 
i want to change a textfield based on one of the fields in the response
but i can't find anywhere on the web on how to do that,

this is my Retrofit Interface:

```
public interface retrofitApi {

    String baseUrl = "http://192.168.137.1:3003/";

    @GET("api/radBox/getDegrees")
    Call<ResponseBody> getCallData();

    //Call<degreesModel> getCallData();


    class Factory {
        private static retrofitApi service;

        public static retrofitApi getInstance() {
            if (service == null) {
                Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .build();

                service = retrofit.create(retrofitApi.class);
                return service;
            } else {
                return service;
            }

        }
    }


}
```

and here is my repsonse:

```
 retrofitApi.Factory.getInstance().getCallData().enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {


//HERE I WANT TO DO RESPONSE.BODY.SOMEHING ?
//HERE I WANT TO DO RESPONSE.BODY.SOMEHING ?


 @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("myLogs", "failed to Retrive Data");
                Log.d("myLogs", "becouse: "+t);
                largeTextVar.setText("failed: " + t);
            }
        });


    }
```

my json is looking like this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "sector": [
      [
        {
          "scanned": false,
          "sectorOne": "",
          "sectorTwo": "",
          "sectorThree": ""
        },
        {
          "scanned": false,
          "sectorOne": "",
          "sectorTwo": "",
          "sectorThree": ""
        }
      ]
    ]
  },
  "curserLocation": {
    "elevation": 30,
    "horizontal": 105
  }
}
```

how do i access from the response to one of the fields in my json ?

THNX ALLOT !!

Comment: Read this : https://guides.codepath.com/android/Consuming-APIs-with-Retrofit

Comment: Is there a reason you want to work with the JSON rather than a bean-type object?

Comment: hi, no not a specific reason just what i came across trying to do it..

Answer (score 0):

You should define some classes to access to your fields. In your case convert your response to proper classes and access them with getter Methods. (you can find Automatic converter [here](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) but I recommend to do it yourself)

Also [this](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/) website give you some view how your classes should be.